# Python socket bind to any IP?

Tags: python, sockets

I have a small one sided message sender that works while I specify the IP to connect to in code, however, I am having trouble allowing the socket to accept connections from any IP. Here is the line that is the problem.

```
mySocket = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
mySocket.bind ( ( '', 2727 ) )
```

The `''` is for localhost, and it works if I manually enter IP, eg `'192.168.1.106'`, however, how can I leave it open to all? Or am I using the wrong connection type for this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you want to bind to all available IPv4 addresses, specify `0.0.0.0` as your IP address. If you're behind a router and wish to have your socket internet-accessible, rather than just available on your LAN, you'll need to set up a port forwarding rule so that users outside your LAN can access the service.

See the following ServerFault question for more info on `0.0.0.0`: https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1

Comment: Is it possible to bind to completely custom ips like 152.64.87.9?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Only if your system has an interface with that address.

Comment: So I would need to create these interfaces prior to binding to them. And creating virtual interfaces would be loopbacks right?

Comment: Would that be IPv4 only? What about binding on all available IPv6 addresses?

Answer (score 16):

Binding to `''` has the same effect as to `'0.0.0.0'` makes the transition to IPv6 easier.

Depending on the OS, opening a `socket.AF_INET6` socket listens to IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: Python bug report to make the docs more explicit about this: https://bugs.python.org/issue33921

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-families), `''` is **not** compatible with IPv6: *This behavior is not compatible with IPv6, therefore, you may want to avoid these if you intend to support IPv6 with your Python programs.*

Answer (score 6):

Binding to 0.0.0.0 will allow it to accept connections from any IPv4 address that can route to it.